# {{ request }} var Empty

Tags: python, django, templates, request, render-to-response

I am running Django 1.9.6
If I try to use `{{ request.path }}` in my templates the var/tag is empty

Here is my settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '_templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
        ],
        'builtins': ['django.templatetags.i18n']
    },
},
```

]

I read that after version 1.8 you need only to include `'django.template.context_processors.request'` and you will have the var running in your templates

I manage to fix the issue if in my VIEW i add

```
return render_to_response('admin-users/events.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What am I doing wrong, because I read many answers which say that I don't have to add `RequestContext`?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `render` method instead, it automatically uses a `RequestContext` to render the template.

```
 return render(request, 'admin-users/events.html', {})
```

The `render_to_response` shortcut is not recommended any more.